# Proof of Pumping Lemma: Why can we set the pumping constant to the number of states?

Tags: automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma, finite-state-machine

I'm learning the proof of the Pumping Lemma for regular languages. The proof is carried out using an arbitrary string having length of at least the number of states in the DFA.
As such:

> The language L is regular, so there exists a DFA M such that L = L(M).
> Say M has p states, {q1, . . . , qp}. We are also given input string s
> ∈ L with s = s1s2 · · · sn (n = |s| ≥ p).

How do we know that the DFA would accept such a string? For example, if we consider this DFA:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R0zt.png

This DFA has 4 states but doesn't accept any string that has length of more than two. So I'm confused about this aspect of the proof.

Comment: You are proving "every sufficiently long string in the language can be pumped". If there are no such strings then this statement is of course also true.

Comment: For DFA that only accepts finite strings, just set pumping length $ p > \text{max length} $, then the lemma is satisfied, since the set of strings whose length larger than $ p $ is empty.

Comment: @nsigma Right, thanks. I missed that this specific proof is for infinite languages.